# Getting all android packages that can handle Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Android 13 API33

Tags: java, android, audio, android-intent, media

In previous versions of Android the following code used to work for getting all packages installed that could handle the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` However, now it does not work as it used to. Does anyone have insight as to why this doesn't work anymore? as well as a new method (Android 13 API 33) for getting the packages that can handle `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`?

```
//get all media players
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
mediaPlayers = this.getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(sendIntent, 0);
```

Comment: What do you have in your `<queries>` element in your manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare nothing that I know of. I never needed anything before for my app, I'm updating an old app for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To comply with [package visibility rules on Android 11 and higher](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility), you will need a `<queries>` element as a child of the root `<manifest>` element, something like:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```